# How to use arrow operators in haskell

Tags: haskell

I want to know the difference between

`->` , `>>=` and `<-`

in haskell and how to use them?

Comment: I'd recommend reading a monad tutorial. E.g. [LYAH](http://learnyouahaskell.com/a-fistful-of-monads) has a chapter dedicated to that topic. You will find many monad tutorial around the net if you google for them.

Comment: Your question shows zero effort of finding the answer yourself. You'll find the answer in any basic introduction to the language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`a -> b` is the function type. It describes a function that takes a type `a` and returns a type `b`.

`>>=` is the monadic bind function. It is of type `Monad m => m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b`. If you need to understand this, I recommend reading [Learn You a Haskell for Great Good](http://learnyouahaskell.com/chapters).

`<-` is syntactic sugar in a `do` block, where `do {a <- b; c}` translates as `b >>= \a -> c`, i.e, it's basically a nicer way of writing `>>=`.

Comment: `->` also appears in `case` statements.