# How do the operators `>>>` and `>>=` work in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, monads, category-theory

I have been reading through a Haskell [d3js](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/d3js) library:

This is the code defining Haskell box:

```
box :: Selector ->  (Double,Double) -> St (Var' Selection)
box parent (w,h) = do
    assign
        $ ((d3Root
            >>> select parent
            >>> func "append" [PText "svg"]
            >>> width w
            >>> height h
            >>> style "background" "#eef") :: Chain () Selection)
```

The code actually exporting using the `box` function in d3.js code uses the `>>=` operator like this:

```
import Control.Monad
import qualified Data.Text as T
import D3JS

test :: Int -> IO ()
test n = T.writeFile "generated.js" $ reify (box "#div1" (300,300) >>= bars n 300 (Data1D [100,20,80,60,120]))
```

---

To avoid being like this unpopular question on arrows: [How to use arrow operators in haskell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33329953/how-to-use-arrow-operators-in-haskell) 
Where can I find the type signatures, or other basic information? 
Are there resources where I can learn more about:

- `$` [Haskell: difference between . (dot) and $ (dollar sign)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/940382/haskell-difference-between-dot-and-dollar-sign?rq=1)
- `>>>` this could be an [arrow](https://www.haskell.org/arrows/) but I don't see where I imported it.
- `>>=`

The first one was easy to find but the answer was confusing:

```
*Main Lib> :t ($)
($) :: (a -> b) -> a -> b
```

I found that `f $ a b c = f ( (a b) c )` while `f a b c = (((f a) b) c`

Prelude gives a similar response for `>>=` involving monads.  In my case, it might be the IO monad.  Or the d3js statement monad `St()`

```
*Main Lib> :t (>>=)
(>>=) :: Monad m => m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b
```

The last one doesn't show up at all... which is too bad because it looks pretty essential

```
*Main Lib> :t (>>>)

<interactive>:1:1:
    Not in scope: ‘>>>’
    Perhaps you meant one of these:
      ‘>>’ (imported from Prelude), ‘>>=’ (imported from Prelude)
```

---

Lastly at the risk of bundling too many questions at once.  Can someone explain this type signature?  Especially the last item:

```
box :: Selector ->  (Double,Double) -> St (Var' Selection)
```

Comment: try https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/

Comment: `>>>` is actually defined in `Control.Category` now. (`Category` is the superclass of `Arrow`.)

Comment: Regarding your last question - I would ask you to answer a counter question - what have you understood about it - and what is giving you problems. Have you looked at the definitions of each type?

Comment: As a nice trick, if you have a chain of `>>>`, you can add a "hole" at any point e.g. change `x1 >>> x2 >>> x3` into `x1 >>> _ >>> x2 >>> x3`. This will make GHC raise an _error_ during compilation, carrying the type which should be used in the hole. You can look up that type on Hoogle, and see what `>>>` is. (Ditto for `>>=`, or many other things).

Comment: @chepner OK I found [`>>>`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/Control-Category.html) on Hoogle.  Do you know which category might be used here?  Does this arrow `>>>` know that automatically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The package Index**

Packages on Hackage usually have an index page of all functions / types / etc. defined. The index for the d3js package is located here:

- https://hackage.haskell.org/package/d3js-0.1.0.0/docs/doc-index.html

You can get there by:

1. Visit the front page for the package
2. Click on any module name in the exported module tree list
3. In the upper right hand corner there are the links `Source | Contents | Index | Style`. Click on the Index link.

**What is `St`?**

`St` is defined as

```
type St r = RWS () Text Int r
```

`RWS` is just a monad which has Reader, Writer and State capabilities. The Reader environment is `()`, it writes `Text` values and an `Int` for state.

It's a convenience definition (available from the `mtl` package) so you don't have to build up your own monad transformer stack using `ReaderT`, `WriterT` and `StateT`.

Note that the reader environment is `()` which means that library is only really using the writer and state aspects of the monad.

**How does `box ... >= box ...` work?**

The `box` function has type:

```
box :: Selector -> (Double, Double) -> St (Var' Selection)
```

which means it takes a `Select` and a pair of Doubles and returns a `Var' Selector` in the `St` monad.

The expression `box "#div1" (300,300) >>= bars n 300 (Data1D [...])` is the same as:

```
do vs <- box "#div1" (300,300)
   bars n 300 (Data1D [...]) vs
```

Interpretation:

1. Run the `box` function to create a `Var' Selection`. This happens in the `St` monad.
2. Call `bars` with the `Var' Selection` returned by step 1.

What's the difference between a `Var' Selection` and a `Selection`? Honestly I'm not sure.

**The `>>>` operator**

`>>>` is an Arrow operator. Arrows is a way of expressing computations as a pipeline of operations. The examples on this page should give you an idea of how it's used:

https://www.haskell.org/arrows/syntax.html

Note that `>>>` is defined in terms of a type-class, so exactly what it does depends on what types you are using it with. In this case it is being used with `Chain () Selection` values.

If you read the docs for `Chain` [(link)](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/d3js-0.1.0.0/docs/D3JS-Type.html#t:Chain) you'll see the comment:

> Chain a b behaves just like (a -> b). Val Var is the starting point of chain (= constant), and Nil is the termination of chain.

So this fragment:

```
                                            -- type:
d3Root >>> select parent                    -- Chain () Selection
       >>> func "append" [PText "svg"]      -- Chain a b
       >>> width w                          -- Chain a a
       >>> height h                         -- Chain a a
       >>> style ...                        -- Chain a a
```

can be read as:

1. Start with the d3 object. This returns a selection.
2. Select the parent of that selection.
3. Call the JS function `append` with argument `"svg"`
4. Set the width then the height and then the style

What's interesting is that the `func` function has type `Chain a b` -- it has an unrestricted return type `b`. That's why I suspect there is the explicit type signature at the end, e.g. `:: Chain () Selection`.

Answer (score 1):

as @delta already said [hoogle](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=%3E%3E%3E) is your friend - the imported piece here is from [`Control.Category`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/Control-Category.html) - and it denotes the *Left-to-right composition* of morphisms.

The category at hand in this case is the <strike>Kleisli Category associated to a monad</strike> just a sub-category of **Hask** - then the `>>>` operator is the <strike>missing</strike> link to make functions like

```
 f :: m a -> m b
 g :: m b -> m c
```

work properly with each other. while

```
>>= :: m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b
```

would not be able to do that, the specialized version of (>>>)

```
>>> :: (m a -> m b) -> (m b -> m c) -> ma -> m c
```

would give you `h = (f >>> g)` a correct output.

Comment: I wouldn't call `m a -> m b` Kleisli. It's just a subcategory of **Hask**. `a -> m b` would be Kleisli. Actually `>>=` (more precisely, `>=>`) composes Kleisli arrows in the plain function form, but `>>>` can only compose them in [their wrapped form](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/Control-Arrow.html#t:Kleisli).

Comment: oh - that was a long time misunderstanding on my part - thanks for telling me